# Using Python and xlsxwriter to concatenate cell references with cell count

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Hi I have a working script to generate a line chart using Xlsxwriter, however I am looking for a way to concatenate an earlier hit count with the cell range for my generated chart as the script is used to iterate over several similar files in the directory so the overall 'hit count' varies for each file.

The script first looks through a text file for a string and collects some stats using line spitting drops the collected figures into Excel and and generates a hit count each time the particular string is found (total)

Then charts are generated using thee collected stats..

Here's my chart generating section...

```
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       'My Chart',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$2200',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$2200',
    'line':   {'color': 'purple'},

})
```

I am hoping to generate the chart by referencing the 'total' count in the row count.  So I am looking for something along the lines of

```
'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$'+total,
'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$'+total,
```

I hope this makes sense? Basically I am looking to have a varying cell row range dependent on the count of hits, is this possible?  Or alternatively is there a 'last row' reference in xlsxwriter for this type of circumstance?

Thanks,
MikG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`chart.add_series()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart.html#chart-add-series) method also accepts a list of values so you can do something like this:

```
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       'My Chart',
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, total -1, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 1, total -1, 1],
    'line':       {'color': 'purple'},
})
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much jmcnamara, works exactly how I was hoping for!